# Getting unary operator error on Shell script Linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I get this error:

```
getengine.sh: line 38: [: =: unary operator expected
getengine.sh: line 41: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Here is the script:

```
if [ $1 = "m" ]; then #this is line 38
    initial=`curl -s http://some/2016/30-publish`
    label=`curl -s http://test/${initial}.l/artifacts/info.xml`
elif [ $1 = "s" ]; then # this is line 41
    initial=`curl -s http://some/2016/30-publish`
    label=`curl -s http://test/${initial}.l/artifacts/info.xml`
fi
```

I don't understand what is wrong? This works perfectly locally but when I run it in a linux environment server I get this error...any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ detects this issue automatically.

Comment: ...btw, what do you expect your code to do when *neither* `m` nor `s` is passed?

Comment: I have an else to print out usage, btw the link you posted has no accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179405/bash-script-error-unary-operator-expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need more quotes.

```
# this is correct
[ "$1" = "m" ]
```

...not...

```
# WRONG: this becomes [ = m ] if $1 is empty, producing your error.
[ $1 = "m" ]
```

Comment: You sure, why is this working locally for me?

Comment: I'm running locally with a mac

Comment: @arabian_albert, yes, I'm sure. The reason it's working locally for you is that you aren't testing with `$1` being empty, whereas it's empty when it runs on the server.

Comment: @arabian_albert, ...though you could *also* be masking the problem by using a non-POSIX-compliant shell such as zsh for your local testing, which doesn't follow POSIX-mandated rules regarding string-splitting of unquoted expansions.

Comment: Hmm...you're solution seemed to have worked however I'm using standard bash shell locally and remotely on the linux server (btw it's rhel 6). $1 is never empty since the parameter $1 is hardcoded.

Comment: Just because it's hardcoded doesn't mean it can't be emptied later. A bad `set` command could do that, f'rinstance, or a `shift`. Use `bash -x yourscript` to see what's actually happening in practice during execution.

Comment: You also could have a value for `IFS` that contains the character literal in question.