# i am getting [: argument excepted in unix command

Tags: shell, unix

I have a code similar to below:

```
while [ $k = 0 ];
do
if [ $Year1 = $Year2 ] && [  $Month1 = $Month2 ]; then
  echo "abcd"
else
  echo"erty"
```

The error is line highlighted line > line 144]: [: argument expected

Comment: Quote your variables! [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script error \[: !=: unary operator expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179405/bash-script-error-unary-operator-expected)

Comment: @Priya : Just a wild guess: One of the variables contains a space. Why don't you run your program with `set -x` and look for yourself, instead of letting everyone guessing?

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your variables contains unexpected data (e.g. is empty, or has spaces or new line characters), causing the `[` command to not receive the arguments it expects.

Always quote your variables (`"$Year1"` instead of `$Year1`) to avoid surprises like this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
while [ "$k" = 0 ]; do if [[ $Year1 == $Year2 && $Month1 == $Month2 ]]; then echo "abcd"; else echo "erty"; fi; done
```

Helpfull could be: https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Inversely, the right-hand operand of `==` and `!=` within `[[...]]` **should** be quoted to avoid surprises when the value contains glob characters -- these operators do not test equality, they are **pattern matching** operators.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `==` for comparisons instead of `=` and also please use `-eq` whenever you want to use `==` if your code is for integer comparison. For example,

```
if [ $FLAG -eq 1 ];then
```

For strings, you can use `=`, like for example **NOTE : Edited as pointed by Sir Athos**

```
if [ "$Year1" = "$Year2" ] && [ "$Month1" = "$Month2" ]; then
```

or if you are comparing variable with string then, you can also use `==`,

```
if [ "$STA" == "Completed" ];then
```

Adding test script to further clarify :

```
-bash-4.2$ cat string.sh
#!/bin/bash -x

str1="Hello There"
str2="Hello There"

if [ "$str1" = "$str2" ];then
        echo "Matched"
else
        echo "Not Matched"
fi

if [ "$str1" == "Hello There" ];then
        echo "Matched"
else
        echo "Not Matched"
fi

-bash-4.2$ ./string.sh 
+ str1='Hello There'
+ str2='Hello There'
+ '[' 'Hello There' = 'Hello There' ']'
+ echo Matched
Matched
+ '[' 'Hello There' == 'Hello There' ']'
+ echo Matched
Matched
-bash-4.2$
```

Comment: This is not true for `==`. If you type `man [` you will find `STRING1 = STRING2` is a valid operator, while `==` is not.

Comment: Edited the answer with the suggestion. Learned something new!

Comment: The information is correct now, with the mention that the `==` part is `bash` specific. Since the question is only tagged `shell`, any other `sh` variant could be in use.

I didn't downvote your answer, but I suspect it was because it doesn't address the question's original problem ("argument expected"). Thanks for the effort to make a complete answer!